# row highlight on mouse over ag grid react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I was trying to highlight a row on mouse over in ag grid. I am using React framework for the same. The React cell styling examples are all related to conditionally rendering styles but none of them are focussed with styling with mouse over. The link I followed was [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styling/)

I have also checked answers over [github](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/223) where they mentioned to use the ag-row-hover class. Where should I be rendering this css class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put the below CSS in your local CSS file to override the .ag-row-hover class.

If you are using `.ag-theme-balham` theme then

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-row-hover{

    background-color: #ECF0F1;
}
```

If you are using `.ag-theme-fresh` theme then

```
.ag-theme-fresh .ag-row-hover{

    background-color: #ECF0F1;
}
```

and so on...